2020 Moderator Election - Results
Cryptography's fourth moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

They'll be joining the existing crew shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.

Let me be the first (well, the umpteenth really, SEJPM and a few others beat me to it on chat) to welcome fgrieu to the mod team! That was a decisive win with over 50% of votes. fgrieu has both excellent meta participation and a lot of reputation here at Cryptography, but I think that the reason for getting such a high vote count is personality formost.
I would also like to congratulate the poncho and kelalaka for participating. They both got about 25% of the votes, which means that there is a lot of respect for these candidates, almost forcing a second round. It was a touch ask considering they were up against fgrieu.
poncho is of course well known for his excellent answers. kelalaka has always been very active when it comes to keeping the site pristine and is well known as dupe hunter. I sincerely hope that they will continue doing this and - of course - run again if / when the opportunity comes up.
